# Duplicate definition of category 'my_framework' on interface 'NSObject'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode7

I am in the process of updating my app and a common library (dynamic framework).  What once was a static library as an Xcode subproject, is now a dynamic framework that contains swift code.

When writing my app's code, I'm seeing some compiler warnings.  At this time, they're only warnings.

In my app's MainViewController I include a file that's written in swift.  And so this has an import of App-swift.h.  Inside of this autogenerated App-swift.h, there is section:

```
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
@import UIKit;
@import my_framework;
#endif
```

Inside of this 'my_framework' I have a category method on various files, e.g. NSObject+my_framework.h

Now, I'm getting a compiler warning for MainViewController.m saying "Duplicate definition of category 'my_framework' on interface 'NSObject'".  The drop down supplies the locations of both definitions.  One location is the actual category header file inside of my framework.  The compiler 'sees' this location via it being included through the pch file.  The other location links directly to my App-swift.h file at the line "@import my_framework".

Is there any way to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 9):

use `@import` or `#import <FMK/FMK.h>` instead `#import "fmk.h"`

Comment: The fix for me, was to rewrite the import line and then error disappeared. Xcode 9.4.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me, I delete the line `module * { export * }` from my_framework.framework/Modules/module.modulemap, so it looks like :

```
framework module my_framework {
   umbrella header "my_framework.h"

   export *
}
```

And the warnings disappeared. Then, added module.modulemap to my_framework project, and setted its path to the MODULEMAP_FILE build setting.

Comment: I removed the "module * { export * }" and I'm still getting these duplicate warnings...
Another note, this framework is getting added from a local dev pod, so the pod install script is involved in this process, and ends up creating the modulemap file dynamically.

Comment: CocoaPod should not create the modulemap for you if you have setted the MODULEMAP_FILE build setting. Maybe you should try with Carthage which doesn't do anything but compiling the framework using xcodebuild.

Answer (score 0):

In my swift project I was using a bridge header to import existing objective-c files. I got this error when I had twice imported a file.